# Connecting HVAC Condensate Line Directly To Sewer

Tags: plumbing, hvac, drain, condensate

I am trying to figure out if I can get rid of my HVAC condensate pump. [It looks like I can attach the P-Trapped condensate line](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/82398/149699) to another P-trap line but can I connect it directly to the sewer line if I have adequate slope as the condensate line is already P-trapped? Should I look at getting a check valve if I connect to the sewer directly? Attached is a picture of what I propose.

[image]

Comment: is there a floor drain available?

Comment: No floor drain nearby. There is a sink that is hooked into that sewer line but I dont think I can get the proper slope if I connect to the sink's P trap. Ideally, I'd like to come in behind the sink's p-trap which is basically connecting directly to the sewer line as shown. I only have about about 3 inches of vertical to work with with the approximately 3ft to the sewer line.

Comment: You only need 3/4" of fall for three feet of pipe run.